# Convert date from iso date format to utc in mongodb query

Tags: c#, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

i am new in mongodb driver.i am trying to filter documents between two date from 06-08-2015 to 06-08-2015 .this is my code

```
IMongoQuery querySubmissionDateFrom = Query<ReviewMDO>.GTE(m => m.SubmissionData.SubmissionDate,manuscriptFilterDocument.Filter.SubmissionFromDate.Date);
     queryFilter.Add(querySubmissionDateFrom);
```

you can see my manuscriptFilterDocument.Filter.SubmissionFromDate.Date filed contain value "06-08-2015 00:00:00" .because in mongodb date is automatically converted to iso date formate.how can i convert this to UTC date formate for comparison.

[image]
 but after add this to query list date value is converted to isodate format
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally i got it.i share my answer to others for reference.i changed my code like this

i use DateTime.SpecifyKind() function for convert datetime to UTC

```
IMongoQuery querySubmissionDateFrom = Query<ReviewMDO>.GTE(m => m.SubmissionData.SubmissionDate, DateTime.SpecifyKind(manuscriptFilterDocument.Filter.SubmissionFromDate.Date, DateTimeKind.Utc) );
            queryFilter.Add(querySubmissionDateFrom);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try LINQ to MongoDB:

```
var collection = database.GetCollection<TDocument>("collectionname");\
var query =
    from e in collection.AsQueryable<Employee>()
    where e.FirstName == "John"
    select e;
```

https://mongodb-documentation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ecosystem/tutorial/use-linq-queries-with-csharp-driver.html

**Edit**

The following is an equalivant of your code:

```
var collection = database.GetCollection<ReviewMDO>("collectionname");
var query =
        from m in collection.AsQueryable<ReviewMDO>()
        where m.SubmissionData.SubmissionDate >= querySubmissionDateFrom
        select m;
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but i am using lambda expression

Comment: I'm pretty sure that what I suggested will work for you.
What you are building is actual BSON filter not LINQ.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use LINQ?

Comment: yes i need to rewrite entire project.i am looking for what is the current issue and how to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with Lambda

```
var date = DateTime.Now;
var results = Collection.Find(x => x.SubmissionDate >= date).ToList();
```

Or to do the same things with the Builders

```
var filter= Builders<ReviewMDO>.Filter.Gte(x => x.SubmissionDate, date);
var results = Collection.Find(filter).ToList();
```